# Reseting Wordpress Salt gives 503 Error

Tags: wordpress, security, salt, http-status-code-503, websecurity

I've recently taken over a friends website that has been hacked. A lot of additional pages were added by third parties. So I did the usual:

1. Change Passwords to something secure
2. remove unused themes and plugins
3. (There is no backup so I can't restore)
4. Update to the latest wp 4.8.2 (we were already here)
5. Run a check against a fresh wp install and the wp admin files (they matched)
6. reset salts in wp-config --> ERROR

Resetting the salts gives me a 503 error.

I thought this was just supposed to invalidate cookies. Any thoughts as to why I can't change the salts without an error?

My current theory is that wherever the malicious code is, it is preventing the change of these, or if they do change give a 503 error.

The wp-config file is standard:

```
    define('DB_NAME', 'my_db_name');
    define('DB_USER', 'my_db_user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'my_db_pass');
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
    define('DB_COLLATE', '');

    define('AUTH_KEY',         'salt-generated-https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/');
    define('SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'salt-generated-https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/');
    define('LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'salt-generated-https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/');
    define('NONCE_KEY',        'salt-generated-https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/');
    define('AUTH_SALT',        'salt-generated-https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/');
    define('SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'salt-generated-https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/');
    define('LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'salt-generated-https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/');
    define('NONCE_SALT',       'salt-generated-https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/');

    $table_prefix  = 'wp_';
    define('WP_DEBUG', false);        
    if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
           define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

    /** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

Cheers
Brendan

Comment: Are you sure your salts are valid / don't cause some sort of parse / syntax error in the PHP file?

Comment: Yes, simple copy paste from the salt generator. I double checked semi colons and ' apostrophes. The only thing I can kind of see is that the current salt looks like 'sivlgtsxcblwvpe3jmcoodrvldvwx' and the new salt looks like '!kB*w`dx./ptKf)9q4s?.qbm$(w,/h'. More special characters in the newly generated salts, but no ' in the middle of the new salt.